# why is this javascript array undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, which attempts to generate a 2 dimensional array of random numbers:

```
var block_size = 32;
var can_width = can.width;
var color_depth = 12;
var passes = can_width / block_size;
var map_store = new Array(passes);

for(i=0;i<passes;i++) {
  for(j=0;j<passes;j++) {
    map_store[i] = new Array(passes);
    color = Math.random() * color_depth;
    map_store[i][j] = Math.round(color);
  }
}
```

which seems to work fine if i put `console.log` statements within the loop, however if I try to access the `map_store` array outside of the loops. all of it's elements are undefined. why is this?

Comment: looks like the last element in the array should have a value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`map_store[i] = new Array(passes);` should be above the 2nd `for` loop. You're clearing your previous `j` values.

```
for(i=0;i<passes;i++) {
  map_store[i] = new Array(passes); // <--
  for(j=0;j<passes;j++) {
    color = Math.random() * color_depth;
    map_store[i][j] = Math.round(color);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also just do `map_store[i] = [];`

Comment: There is no real benefit in this case as you know the length of the Array before hand. Why is `[]` generally better than `new Array`? (I know it is, but I don't know why)

Comment: @Frits van Campen Style really -- since the language *has* a built-in feature, might as well take advantage of it (even though `new Array(len)` and `[]` are slightly different when `len` is not 0). It should also be noted that [Array constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is somewhat special in how it treats arguments. That is, `[x]` and `new Array(x)` are different while `[x,y]` and `new Array(x,y)` are the same. Awesome design :)

Comment: What Frits van Campen has is fine if you care for speed.  Declaring new Array(500) and then overwriting each element is generally faster than var foo = []; and 500 pushes barring VM-specific optimizations.  See my post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375120/why-arr-is-faster-than-arr-new-array/7375418#7375418 for a detailed explanation from a performance perspective.  You'll find in high-performance JS libs, new Array(x) is still used.  Of course, we don't want pre-mature optimization either :); however, the point is that `[]` - like all best practices - is not a "law."